# Grails logging during integration test

Tags: grails, testing, logging, log4j

I know that this issue has occurred in stackoverflow for few times but they were reflecting to old version of Grails and solutions didn't work for me. I am using 2.2.3 version now.

So problem is that my service/controller/whatever logs are not show on console during integraion tests and when I run application (grails run-app) they are shown.

My log4j config looks like this :

```
environments {

        test {
            root {
                error 'stdout'
            }
            debug 'grails.app.services'
            debug 'grails.app.controllers'
            debug 'grails.app.domain'
        }

        development {
            root {
                error 'stdout'
            }
            debug 'grails.app.services'
            debug 'grails.app.controllers'
        }
}
```

And my test extend IntegrationSpec.

To make this more crazy and frustrating sometimes I see logs and sometimes not.
Anyone has some idea?

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: I was able to see the logs in the test reports when I tested, with your configuration for `log4j`. See if you are able to see them in the test report. On the contrary, you should be able to see the same logs in console instead of test-report for Grails version 2.3.4.